# Pygame screen resolution

Tags: gpio, python, screen, composite-video

I creating a data logger program in Python for a customer.
I use pygame for displaying status and temperature. We plan to using a car display on the composite video output. The display will have 320x240 pixel resolution.
I had only a CRT TV to develop on. Pygame reported 656x416 pixel resolution on it.

If I position everything on the CRT TV is it possible to run it on the car display with more or less accurate position ?

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If so, please mark the answer that helped you, or if you solved it on your own, create a self-answer and mark it as such. We are trying to get the site Q:A ratio up and marking answers is what does that. If you resolved it and mark then people in the future will be able to profit from what you did *and* it helps move the site closer to graduation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The positions will be accurate, since the car TV display simply downscales the entire image. You need to pay attention to small elements, as they will be illegible. Single-pixel-wide lines and small fonts will not be visible at all.

You may wish to take some screen captures in your program, and then resize the to 320x240 to see how it will actually look on the TV.

Answer (score 0):

if i were you, i'd ask for a short session with the actual car display, where you learn about the actual screen size and show some basic geometric figures to find out where the edges are and how "square" are the screen pixels. after that it's easy to develop on any other screen, as long as you remember the boundaries and limitations.

Comment: My customer is in another country. But thanks for the tip anyway.

Comment: EMS takes less than a week for most countries and costs about $20-30. on the other hand, you may send the code to the customer and ask him/her to take resulting pictures. I'd draw some vertical/horizontal lines about 10 pixels apart along with the pixel count, that should give you the screen geometry and size.